# get_site_url is not returning anything?

Tags: urls, links

I'm using the twentyten theme with the bbpress plugin.
I have the following in my header.php (twentyten):

```
    <div id="masthead">
        <div id="branding" role="banner">
            <h1><a href="<?php get_site_url(); ?>">TaiwanTalk</a></h1>
        </div><!-- #branding -->
        <div id="access" role="navigation">
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </div><!-- #access -->
    </div><!-- #masthead -->
```

`get_site_url` doesn't return anything.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The functions that start with "get_" return the value to what's calling it. So you would do `<a href="<?php echo get_site_url(); ?>">` instead to print out the URL.

Comment: Damn, I feel so stupid I always forget the echo stuff. Thanks!

Comment: You're more than welcome. :)

Answer (score 1):

The function is located in wp-includes/link-template.php. You can take a look at the code [here](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-includes/link-template.php), and see if there are any conditions that look like they could be the problem. If not, then you can either debug, or use "echo" in order to see where the code goes, and what is missing